# Translation for "...걸려 나올 미끼..."

Tags: translation

[image]

I'm not sure for the second sentence. Is this right?
"Let's make it as a bait. There's a lot of hiding places, but esphere is going to come out to take the bait"

Comment: Hi Arin - as you will see from https://korean.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, this site does allow questions involving translations, but "where the context, and any specific difficulties encountered, are made as clear as possible". Perhaps you could add a bit more context (i.e. explain the story) and highlight the specific difficulties you are having a little more? What is it about this sentence that is difficult?

Answer (score 3):

I think you understand the gist of the sentence. This is my translation:

> I'm saying we should set up a bait. A bait that can make all the *espheres* come out of their hiding places here and there.

The Korean text reads:

> 미끼를 만들자는 겁니다.
>
> 곳곳에 숨어있는 에시페르
>
> 그것들이 모두
>
> 걸려나올 미끼를

The second line is a phrase serving as the antecedent to "그것" in the third line, and the last two lines are expansion of "미끼" in the first line.

Vocabulary-wise, I think you can understand most with a dictionary, but I'm leaving a note that using the compound verb 걸려나오다 (literally, "to be hung and to come out") to modify 미끼 ("bait) is kind of making an image of a fish and a lure.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a bait, **which makes it possible that** all 에시페르 hiding
at several places would be taken (under a trap) and be came out.

Consider this sentence : When we do not translate **bold**, then 미끼를 만들자, 곳곳에 숨어있는 모든 에시페르, 걸려 나오다.

So we have 곳곳에 숨어 있는 모든 에시페르가 걸려 나오는 것을 **가능하게 하는** 미끼를 만들자.